# Applying resizable() on an Image affects text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I am working on SwiftUI to make a widget and I can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong or there's a bug in SwiftUI.

I have an Image that I use as a background and at the top there's a text. If I apply resizable() to the Image it also affects the behaviour of the text.

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image(affirmation.customImageName ?? "c_0")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .clipped()
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text(affirmation.title)
                    .font(.body)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
        }
    }
```

Creates this view:

[image]

While this code:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Image(affirmation.customImageName ?? "c_0")
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .clipped()
            }
            
            HStack {
                Text(affirmation.title)
                    .font(.body)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading, 5)
            .padding(.top, 5)
        }
    }
```

Creates this view:

[image]

Comment: To compare it is better to show same image and same text... I don't see much difference... it might be only due to optical effect. And VStack around Image is redundant.